# Exclude 'id' from being retrieved from query in Grails

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I have to display a list of items with their details.
The controller looks like this

```
def showItems() {
    def items = Item.list(offset:0, max:10, sort:"updatedOn", order:"desc")
    render view : "show", model : [items : items]
}
```

This works perfectly fine but the problem is that the 'id' of the items is also being sent to the gsp which I don't want. How can I send all the item details from the controller to the gsp except the 'id'.

Comment: for specific query use criteria and projections.

Comment: why don't you want to "send" ids to the gsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you care about the ID being sent to the view, but, you can do something like:

```
Item.list().collect { [prop1: it[prop1], ...] }
```

to send only the properties you want.

Another option:

```
Item.list().collect { it.subMap('key1', 'key2') }
```

And even more Groovy:

```
Item.list().collect{ 
    def keys = it.keySet()
    keys.remove('id')
    it.subMap( keys ) 
}​​
```